# Integrate jboss4 jms with jboss6

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jboss6.x, jboss-4.2.x

I would like to know if this scenario is possible:

1. I Have Topic jms at jboss6
2. I have mdb at jboss-4.2.3.GA.

Is it possible for the MDB(jboss-4.2.3.GA) to lookup for the jms(jboss6.0) straight forward or there is a need to add some libraries?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not straightforward.  JBossAS 4.x and 6.x use completely different (and incompatible) JMS implementations (JBossMQ and HornetQ, respectively).

The JBoss webaite does have documentation of a bridge between the two ([Integrating HornetQ 2.1.1 and JBoss AS 4, with JMS bridge](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/IntegratingHornetQ211AndJBossAS4WithJMSBridge)), but it looks like quite a lot of work.

Comment: So basically as I read your link the only way is using some bridge between the the two?

Comment: Thank you. mybe you could look at my other question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686248/error-creating-stateless-bean-with-annotations   I understand you have knowledge with jboss4. thanks again.